# Gettign values from jquery ajax sucess using jason

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I can;t find an answer to my simple problem on the web.

I have

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Getmessage",
                data: "{'uid': '" + "XX" + "' }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: OnFailure
            });
        });
        function OnSuccess(data) {
            $("#lblMessageReceived").html(data.uid + data.text);
        }
        function OnFailure() {
            alert("Error");
        }
```

Server side I have

```
Public Class clsResponseData
    Public Property uid As String
    Public Property text As String = "Hello"
End Class

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function getMessage(uid As String) As String
     Dim rd As New clsResponseData
     rd.uid = uid
     Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rd)
End Function
```

When I run the code I get

```
    "data" as Object {d: "{"uid":"XX","text":"Hello"}"}
and then 
    "data.d" as "{"uid":"XX","text":"Hello"}"
but then
    "data.d.uid" returns undefined
so how do I reference the value of "uid" and "text"? .
```

I have tried this code with the Visuals Studio editor and Chrome browser insepction. What else do I need to add?

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working

Comment: Not really spam! Would it help if you read the post?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone looks for this, i cound the answer is to add an eval() function

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
         eval('var t =' + data.d);
         $("#lblMessageReceived").html(t.uid + t.text);
        }
```

Comment: Did you try JSON.parse?